# Multiple Hide/Show Text

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello, I'd like to inquire how to create multiple hidden/show more coding for my WordPress site. I am having issues with the following code below, the source is getting mixed up. How do I differentiate the two? Please help, thank you!**

```
--Script1--
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "Click here for complete details.";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "Hide details.";
}
} 
</script><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Click here for complete details.</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">Details</div>
</span>

--Script2--
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "Click here for more information.";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "Hide Disclaimer.";
}
} 
</script><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Click here for more information.</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">Information</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Try this using `class` instead of `id` and `this` property will surely help

Comment: your are using same `id ` both script and html ,now you can use different `id`

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of  `function` and the `id`.
i hope this answer will helps.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "Click here for complete details.";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "Hide details.";
}
} 
</script><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Click here for complete details.</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">Details</div>
</span>

--Script2--
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle1() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText1");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "Click here for more information.";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "Hide Disclaimer.";
}
} 
</script><a id="displayText1" href="javascript:toggle1();">Click here for more information.</a>
<div id="toggleText1" style="display: none">Information</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, adding a second method with the same name replace the previous one.

So instead you should add parameters to the function and pass them when calling it.

```js
function toggle(ele) {
 var text = ele.nextElementSibling;
 if (text.style.display == "block") {
  text.style.display = "none";
  ele.innerHTML = ele.getAttribute('data-initial-text');
 } else {
  text.style.display = "block";
  ele.innerHTML = ele.getAttribute('data-hide-text');
 }
}
```

```html
<a data-initial-text='Click here for complete details.' data-hide-text='Hide details.' href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle(this);">Click here for complete details.</a>
<div style="display: none">Details</div>

<a data-initial-text='Click here for more information.' data-hide-text='Hide Disclaimer.' href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle(this);">Click here for more information.</a>
<div style="display: none">Information</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give different id for the elements as the id should be unique. And also define different function names. You are using the same function name:

Please try below code:

```
function toggle1() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText1");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Click here for complete details.";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide details.";
    }
} 
</script>
<a id="displayText1" href="javascript:toggle1();">Click here for complete details.</a>
<div id="toggleText1" style="display: none">Details</div>


<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle2() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText2");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText2");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Click here for more information.111";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide Disclaimer.111";
    }
} 
</script>
<a id="displayText2" href="javascript:toggle2();">Click here for more information.</a>
<div id="toggleText2" style="display: none">Information</div>
```